# RemoteView and wrong layout_weight

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-appwidget, remoteview

I have a problem with layout_weight and the remoteView of my appWidget.

All my toggle are like this
[image: my toggles]

With this xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/btn"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:background="@drawable/appwidget_button_center"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:visibility="visible" >

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toggle_img"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:scaleType="center" />
    
         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toggle_txt"
            style="@style/TextSmallButton" 
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toggle_ind"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/b7_on" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Now I want one of my toggle to take double size than default size so i put layout_weight = 2 on my xml only for the specific toggle. And now I have this :
[image: Now]

If i do this in my activity it's work i have :
[image: What i want]

So how can i resolve this please...